# Equivalence of left action and right action

Tags: group-theory

I need a hint for this problem:
Suppose $G$ has a left action on a set $A$, denoted by $g\cdot a$ for all $g\in G$ and $a\in A$. Denote the corresponding right action on $A$ by $a\cdot g$. Now define
$$ a R b \quad \text{iff} \quad a=g\cdot b \quad \text{for some $g \in G$}$$
$$ a R' b \quad \text{iff} \quad a=b\cdot g \quad \text{for some $g \in G$}$$

Prove that $aRb$ if and only if $aR'b$.

The problem is from a chapter of conjugacy classes. I tried analyzing the orbits but could not figure it out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the "corresponding right action" is defined via $a \cdot g = g^{-1}\cdot a$. That's the most reasonable way to produce a right action from a given a left action.

If that's the case then $aRb \Rightarrow \exists g\, a=g \cdot b \Rightarrow \exists g\, a = b \cdot g^{-1}$, and similarly for the other implication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's how is written in Dummit&Foote section 4.3, problem 1. So it is ambiguous ... hmm

Comment: It is explained earlier in section 4.3 (section titled "Right group actions", starting on p. 128 in my edition.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what "the corresponding right action" means.

Take $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}$ under addition.  Let the left action be addition, let the right action be trivial.  Then this is not true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just edited the answer so it looks exactly like Dummit&Foote section 4.3.